# What two functions can i graph to produce a circle?

Tags: number-theory, implicit-differentiation

So I'm of the understanding that a function is defined as only ploting one point per input. I'm being taught implicit differentiation so am now thinking about circles, ovals and rotated quadratics. I feel the route to my answer is probably through the rotated quadratic seens as a circle is fundementaly a closed ... ("system"?).

What two functions can i graph to produce an enclosed circular shape?
*Edit*
I'm looking for two equations in terms of y

Comment: Isolate $y$ in your circle equation. As $y$ appears as $y^2$ in the equation of a circle, or of a hyperbola, you will have $2$ answers, hence $2$ functions.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ where $r$ is the radius. Taking branches of the squareroot will allow you to plot this

Comment: @benbridge Why is this question tagged number-theory and why implicit-differentiation?

Comment: @PeterMelech Where should it be?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Branches of the square root?

Comment: Maybe circles or something similar, just asking because it is not related to number-theory and You don't differentiate, neither directly nor implicitely@benbridge

Comment: @PeterMelech Read my question i think its pretty clear why I've tagged as i have. Nice stats you've got there pc4pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use
$$ y = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$
$$ y = -\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$$

For a circle of radius $r$ centered at $O$, with the equations representing the top and bottom semi-circles respectively.